# Hive is throwing permission error while creating table/database

Tags: hadoop, hive, permission-denied

I am getting permission error in hive.

I am using IBM cloud -
[my.imdemocloud.com](http://my.imdemocloud.com/bigsql/3292)

`hive> create table a(key INT);
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=nehpraka, access=WRITE, inode="warehouse":biadmin:biadmin:rwxrwxr-x)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask`

Where as I have given all the roles to m user.

`hive> SHOW GRANT USER nehpraka on DATABASE default;
OK`

`database default
principalName nehpraka 
principalType USER
privilege Create
grantTime Wed Apr 16 14:17:51 EDT 2014
grantor nehpraka
Time taken: 0.051 seconds`

Please help me out in this.

Thanks & Ragards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution.

I was using IBM Big Insight cloud, on this we can create a database in this manner.

```
create database DataBaseName location 'hdfs://master-1-internal.imdemocloud.com:9000/user/<user_name>';
```

Thanks all for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a HDFS folder write permission issue.

Have you tried with hdfs user? Basically check the warehouse of hive on HDFS and that folder should have RW permission for your user.

Comment: I am not permitted to do so, I am using IBM's cloud
http://bigsql.imdemocloud.com/­
https://my.imdemocloud.com­     I am not authorized.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Cloudera version of hadoop and hive then try to open hive using below command :

```
sudo hive
```

if it asks for password then enter **`cloudera`**.
In cloudera version, only super user have permission to hive write permissions on hdfs.
This will help you.

Comment: I am using IBM cloud

http://bigsql.imdemocloud.com/­
https://my.imdemocloud.com­

Comment: For some strange reason my Cloudera installation managed to initialize Hive only as user `hdfs`. Something like `sudo -u hdfs hive`.